# CursorLoader и вопрос потокобезопасности

Tags: android, sqlite

Господа, кто может разъяснить вопрос?
В своем приложении использую CursorLoader в связке с LoaderManager. Делаю это исключительно для получения данных из бд. И озадачился вопросом как обеспечить потокобезопасность данной связки. С loadermanager все понятно, а вот с cursorloader не очень. 
Провел эксперимент, в методе который выполняет получение данных от бд после db.query но перед return cursor сделал задержку в одну секунду, а в активности два раза подряд вызываю loadermanager. Приложение отработало нормально, ничего не вылетело и второй запрос вернулся как ответ. Но при этом я ни разу не использовал sinchronized. Как я понял то при использовании SQLiteDatabase все будет нормально т.к. он является потокобезопасным и оба запроса выполнятся последовательно. Вроде как все понятно, но ничего не понятно. Как все таки SQLiteDatabase обеспечивает потокобезопасность?
Вот код который реализует запрос данных из бд.

```
public Cursor getEmployees() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String sqlTables = "Test";

    String SELECTION_DB = COLUMN_NAME_STATION + " LIKE " + "'" + searchName + "%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(sqlTables, null, SELECTION_DB, null, null, null, null);

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
```

Код который написан в классе унаследованном от CursorLoader

```
protected Cursor onLoadInBackground()
{
    DbOfStationsSearch db = new DbOfStationsSearch(getContext(), bundle.getString("upd"));
    Cursor cursor = db.getEmployees();
    return cursor;
}
```

В активности написано следующее

```
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, MainActivity.this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase` никак не обеспечивает потокобезопасность. Вызывая `CursorLoader` (который наследуется от `AsyncTaskLoader`) выполняет запросы асинхроно.

Comment: В этом то и заключается вопрос. Ведь получается я из разных потоков обращаюсь к одной базе данных и никакой метод не синхронизирую. При этом приложение не падает. почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite - полноценная реляционрая база данных. Она расчитана на работу со [множеством пользователей одновременно](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html). В данном случае в роли пользователей выступают разные потоки, это не принципиально. То есть, со стороны кода не требуется обеспечивать какую-то потокобезопасность, сама БД потокобезопасна.